# TabStop/TabIndex behaves erratically within TableLayoutPanel

Tags: .net, winforms, tabindex, tabstop, tab-ordering

I've got a rather complex `TableLayoutPanel` with close to 40 controls on it. Some are read-only, and some don't need user attention unless in very special cases (which can then be accessed with mouse). So I'd like to set `TabStop=false` to those controls, and arrange the rest in top-down left-to-right order.

However for any control inside the `TableLayoutPanel` I cannot change the `TabStop` property. That is, I can, but it gets reset to `False` upon the next rebuild. Consequently all controls can be reached by the TAB key, even the ones I don't want to be reachable.

What is going on here?

Environment: Windows 7 Enterprise; VS2008; .NET 3.5 SP1; All controls are placed directly on the `TableLayouPanel`, there are no intermediary containers.

**Added more info:** Robert Kerr reports that he is unable to reproduce. I forgot to mention that I used exclusively Telerik Winforms RadControls on the TableLayoutPanel. It also seems that buttons/checkboxes work fine, while textboxes, comboboxes and spinedits do not.

Comment: i'm having the same freaking behavior! have the same development enviroment as well, all but the telerik controls as i'm using infragistics...

Comment: Hmm... are you perchance using Panels inside the table cells? Think carefully. I think I overlooked mine and that was the problem... but I can't remember now.

Answer (score 0):

More info required.  I was unable to duplicate the problem.  Created a TableLayoutPanel, set to 4 rows, 4 columns, and randomly populated with Buttons, TextBoxes, RadioControls, CheckBoxes.  Then set on a couple of each, Tabstop to False.  Repeatedly rebuilt and executed the application and it worked as expected.  Only the controls with True for Tabstop were reachable by tabbing.  At no time did the Tabstop value reset to default (true).
(VS2008, .NET 3.5 SP1, WinSVR2003)

Comment: Hmm... maybe then it's the Telerik controls that I'm using?